# Get element using JQuery with webpack

Tags: spring-boot, webpack, bundle

I have a simple springboot application and I am using webpack for bundling js.
I am using JQuery, JQuery-UI to for some UI action.

In my JS file i have below code

```
import 'jquery-ui/themes/base/datepicker.css';
import 'jquery-ui/ui/core';
import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/datepicker';

$(function(){
  console.log("page2 is called");
  $("#mydatepicker").datepicker(); //converts element into Date Picker, works correctly

  $("#btn3").on("click", function() {
    console.log("btn3 clicked.....");
    console.log("date selected jq: " + $('#mydatepicker').value); /// **gives undefined** see screenshot attached
    console.log("date selected js: " + document.getElementById("mydatepicker").value); //this works perfectly
  });
});
```

If i try to access element using *document.getElementById* it works as expected but when i try same using JQ syntax then its not working.
[image]

I tried moving function outside of on ready function, as below

```
window.btnClick = (param) => {
   console.log("btn clicked with param "+param);
   console.log("mydatepicker: "+mydatepicker)
   var dateSelected = mydatepicker.value;
   var lead = $("#mydatepicker");
   console.log("date selected jq: "+lead.value); //still undefined
   console.log("date selected js: "+document.getElementById("mydatepicker").value); //works as expected
}
```

Not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#mydatepicker')[0].value
```

should work, basically `.value` is a DOM object attribute not a jQuery object attribute

If you want to use solely jQuery try `$('#mydatepicker').attr('value')`

***Edit***: as pointed out by @java_baba: $().val() also returns current value of element selected

Comment: $('#mydatepicker')[0].value  works, thanks.
But can you explain why we need to access it that way? if i understand correctly $('#mydatepicker') should give us jq element, right?
$('#mydatepicker').attr('value') did not worked, i tried below
 ```console.log("date selected jq: " + $('#mydatepicker').attr('value'));````

Comment: @java_baba right so when when you use `$()` (or any jQuery selector) it returns a jQuery object with a limited set of attributes (see full list here https://api.jquery.com/category/attributes/). This means that you can't access html attributes directly, but need to use jQuery methods, adding [0] at the end of a valid jQuery selector, converts the object to the DOM object, and then `.value` works as expected. Hope this clears things up, also not sure why `.attr('value')` didn't work, I verified an example in my console so not sure.

Comment: i looked into link provided by you, which says :
.val()
Get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements or set the value of every matched element.

tried   console.log("date selected jq1: " + $('#mydatepicker').val());
and it works as expected. Although not sure why $('#mydatepicker').attr('value') is not working, but you answer really helped me understand behaviour, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @java_baba oh wow have been using jQuery for a year now never realized .Val() existed, thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: $('#mydatepicker').val("01/01/1900"); also sets value, so i guess .val(..) is good way to get/set value. imo :)

Comment: indeed @java_baba 